# method returns memory stream and add to task list to await

Tags: c#

My goal here is to call a bunch of reports and await them. I've done this successfully with a void (where I wrote the report to file system) but now I am trying to return a memory stream.

I have a feeling this is rather easy but I am having trouble finding it on the internet.

Here's what I have tried...

Here is get reprot in full

```
    public static async Task<MemoryStream> GetReport(CRApieces piece)
        //string DUNS,string filepathName)
    {
        using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
        {
            bool retry = true;
            int retryCt = 0;

            if (piece.ReportNameURL != null)
            {
                if(piece.cred!=null)
                    wc.Credentials = piece.cred;

                while (retry)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        return new MemoryStream(await wc.DownloadDataTaskAsync(piece.ReportNameURL));
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        retryCt++;
                        if (retryCt >= 10) { retry = false; }
                    }
                }
            }
        }


        public class CRApieces
        {
            public string ReportNameURL { get; set; }
            public string TOCName { get; set; }
            public NetworkCredential cred { get; set; }
            public MemoryStream ms { get; set; }

        }


            List<CRApieces> pieces = new List<CRApieces>();
            //Add members

        List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
        for(int i = 0; i<pieces.Count;i++)
        {
            pieces[i].ms = tasks.Add(GetReport(pieces[i])); //Obviously this is my problem line
        }

        await Task.WhenAll(tasks.ToArray());
```

My problem is that I want to both add an item to the tasks and return a memory stream.

Comment: Does `GetReport` return a MemoryStream?  What is `pieces`?  What is actually going wrong?

Comment: This question should include more details and clarify the problem.

Comment: GetReport returns memory stream. piece is a List<class>. I'll add the defintion

Comment: You should follow some naming conventions.

Comment: public static async Task<MemoryStream> GetReport(CRApieces piece)

Comment: Can you add the implementation of `GetReport` to the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be something like that:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<CRApieces> pieces = new List<CRApieces>();

        //Add members

        Task<MemoryStream>[] tasks = new Task<MemoryStream>[pieces.Count];

        for (int i = 0; i < tasks.Length; i++)
        {
            tasks[i] = Task.Run(async () => await GetReport(pieces[i]));
        }

        Task.WaitAll(tasks);

        for(int i = 0; i < tasks.Length; i++)
        {
            pieces[i].Stream = tasks[i].Result;
        }
    }

    private static async Task<MemoryStream> GetReport(CRApieces piece)
    {
        return await Task.FromResult(new MemoryStream());
    }
}

public class CRApieces
{
    public string ReportNameURL { get; set; }
    public string TOCName { get; set; }
    public NetworkCredential Credential { get; set; }
    public MemoryStream Stream { get; set; }
}
```